# How to start insert-mode completion from select mode using Vimscript?

Tags: visual-mode, ins-completion, selection

I have some text selected in select mode.  I want to delete it and start insert-mode completion.

When I type these keystrokes into Vim it works perfectly:

```
gvc<C-X><C-U>
```

`gv` switches to visual mode; `c` changes / cuts the selection and switches to insert mode; and the rest triggers insert-mode completion.

However when I try to this from Vimscript it doesn't work:

```
execute "normal! gvc\<C-X>\<C-U>"
```

The `gv` part works but the `c` cuts a character extra at the right hand end of the selection, and the cursor ends up one character before where I want it (in insert mode, which is correct), and the completion doesn't start.

For example, if `bar` is selected in the following line:

```
foo(bar, baz
```

– then after my `execute "normal! ..."` I am left with:

```
foo( baz
```

– with the cursor just before the bracket.  What I want is `foo(, baz` with the cursor just after the bracket and the completion menu open.

How can I get this working via Vimscript?

Comment: Why do you need execute? Try `normal! gvc<C-X><C-U>`.

Comment: You need it so you can escape the key sequence; without it you get the literal text `<C-X><C-U>` inserted.  See `:help expr-quote`.